# Use 2 legged in Google API v3 for python

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have the code as describe here.
I need to create a lot of events in my calendar.

I cannot find a way to make it work. Using 2 legged seems to be deprecated

```python
import sys
import httplib2
from  rfc3339 import rfc3339
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run
import pytz
import datetime
import time
start_zone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
end_zone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Oslo')

start_time = datetime.datetime(2013,8,13,15,0, tzinfo=start_zone)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2013,8,16,19,0, tzinfo=end_zone)


flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost')

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

try:

  event = {
    'start': {
      'dateTime': start_time
      },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': end_time
      },
    "summary": "New event",
    "location": "Paris, FRANCE"
  }
  service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
  print "END"
except AccessTokenRefreshError:
  print ('Credentials have been revoked')
```

I have updated my code this way (since i don't have redirection)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import httplib2
from  rfc3339 import rfc3339
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run
import pytz
import datetime
import time
start_zone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
end_zone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Oslo')

start_time = datetime.datetime(2013,8,13,15,0, tzinfo=start_zone)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2013,8,16,19,0, tzinfo=end_zone)

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print('Visit this site!')
print(auth_uri)
code = raw_input('Insert the given code!')
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
print(credentials)

with open('credentials.dat', 'wr') as f:
  f.write(credentials.to_json())

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

try:
  event = {
    'start': {
      'dateTime': start_time
      },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': end_time
      },
    "summary": "New event",
    "location": "Paris, FRANCE"
  }
  service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
  print "END"
except AccessTokenRefreshError:
  print ('Credentials have been revoked')
```

So when I run my script, it opens a window ad asking me to login. So I put my gmail username/password and I have the following error after that:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered redirect URI
```

Comment: The authentication portion of your code seems correct. What error are you getting on execution?

Comment: @jay-lee,  Hello Jay, I have updated my question. Hopefully it make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the client_secrets.json you used is not for an installed application. Try recreating the Client ID in the API Console and making sure you specify it's an installed application.